# Benefits on splitting data in MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have worked in a project that had a table somewhat like this:

```
tbl_texts
id, item_id, item, type, lang, value
1, 44, 'product', 'name', 'en', 'Product Name'
2, 44, 'product', 'description', 'en', 'Product description'
3, 55, 'category', 'name', 'en', 'Category name'
4, 55, 'category', 'name', 'fi', 'Category finnish name'
```

Out of the 6 fields, 1 was primary key and 4 was a combined index. Data was never selected with the primary key. Item_id, item, type, lang index was always used.

1) I was wondering if this is a good or a bad way to store data?

2) Is it bad design to have a table that you have to join twice (incase you want the name and description of a product).

3) Should I separate the data to tables like these:

```
tbl_product_texts
id, product_id, type, lang, value

tbl_category_texts

(etc.)
```

4) Or like this:

```
tbl_product_names
id, product_id, lang, name

tbl_product_descriptions
id, product_id, lang, description

(etc.)
```

5) Or even like this:

```
tbl_product_names_en
id, product_id, name

tbl_product_descriptions_en
id, product_id, description

(etc.)
```

I'm really confused which is the most optimal way to do this.

Comment: . . The way your store the data should be driven by how the data is used (loaded, maintained, queried).  There is not necessarily a "best" way for all circumstances, and your question does not contain information on how the data is being used.

Comment: It very much depends on how dynamic those structures are. If you quite a long time have product name and product description, then they would be better as two columns. But if categories are added often or could be added over admin-frontend, the structure you gave is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The 'best' way of storing data is a very open ended question. When designing a schema for data storage you need to take into account multiple aspects:

- How is your data accessed? (query optimisation)
- How is your data created?
- How likely is your database schema going to change in the future?

Wikipedia has a good article on data normalization here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Personally I would create tables that make sense based on the underlying data. If products are sufficiently distinct to categories then I would store them in differing tables. While you have only provided a small sample of data, I am going to make the assumption that each product would have multiple names and description, but only one entry for each language. With that you would have the following:

```
Products:
  PK: id
  ...other columns that each product only has a single value for (price for example)

Product_Texts:
  PK,FK: product_id 
  PK:    language
         name
         description
```

(PK - Primary Key, FK - Foreign Key)

If you then have queries that search for Names or Descriptions, you can then consider adding further keys on those fields as required.

Comment: With this solution I would have to join the table twice if I wanted the name and the description of a product. Is this good design?

Comment: why would you need to join twice? a single join should be sufficient to pull both name and description for a single product id and language: SELECT * FROM Products AS p LEFT JOIN Product_Texts AS pt ON p.id = pt.product_id WHERE p.id = 1 and pt.language='english'.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is a bad implementation depends on what you want to do with it. This looks like it was designed for a variable combination of items, types and languages. The only one that stands out is the item column, which might not be needed since you already have the item_id.

If the current implementation works and it has no performance issues, there is probably no need to change anything. After all, improving the current situation will take time that might be better spend fixing important issues or building new features.

If this setup causes problems, you'll have to look into your requirements. For example, if you know there are a fixed amount of possible types that are always present for every item, this could be a solution (example only two possible types):

```
tbl_texts
id, item_id, item, lang, name_value, desc_value
1, 44, 'product', 'en', 'Product Name', 'Product description'
3, 55, 'category', 'en', 'Category name', 'Category description'
4, 55, 'category', 'fi', 'Category finnish name', 'Category finnish description'
```

You will have halved the amount of records and you have removed one search criterium, offsetting the extra columns that were added. Multiple optional types will likely make this solution a lot worse, an unknown amount of types will make it impossible.